# Alternative to Boolean OR in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I have/had a mysql query that was pretty fast using in e.g.

```
FieldA in (X,Y,Z)
```

I've moved over to Sphinx which is clearly much faster EXCEPT when using pipes in case like this e.g.

```
@(FieldA) (X|Y|Z)
```

Where X|Y|Z are actually about 40 different values. The MysQl In takes .3 seconds the Sphinx takes over a minute. Given how much faster Sphinx has proven to be I am wondering if there is some 'IN' version for Sphinx with multiple values vs | which clearly is slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Really it depends on a lot of things. For certain queries, changing to use a MVA might better than using keywords. (they you do have an 'IN' function )

... particularly if you have other search keywords.

Sphinxes full-text indexing is optimized for answering short user entered queries. To answer a long 'OR' style query, it has to load and merge each wordlist. And rank all that. Its all overhead.

Whereas attribute based filtering is generally pretty quick, particully if you have a highly selective keyword query, which gives a relatively short list of potential matches.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the MVA page in the documentation and while it makes some sense to me vaguely for now, I get the feeling it is a bad solution for me in this case. I'd have to index for 100s of 1000s of possibilities and then 100s of values for each one. Is there a way therefor to combine a Sphinx Query with a MySql one? So I can do e.g "from idx where MATCH('Appel)" and "from table where in (1,2,3,..,N')?

Comment: Well actully not sure it needs MVA, just a standard single value Attribute would be enough. Just one value per document right? - no can't mix and match SPhinx and Mysql directly. They are completely different systems